Problemas con package en .net 8.0
Tengo esta vulnerabilidad a la hora de desplegar el dockerfile de mi proyecto .net 8.0. Ya eh intentado actualizarlo al 8.0.8 y todavia sale esa vulnerabilidad.
Archivo del dockerfile.
# Usa la última versión de .NET SDK 8.0 en Alpine
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine
RUN apk update && apk upgrade 

# Configuraciones de entorno
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug
ENV DOTNET_EnableDiagnostics=0
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:7018
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true 
ENV DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/tmp 

# Exponer el puerto 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Definir el directorio de trabajo y copiar archivos del proyecto
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Sido-Api-Data/Sido-Api-Data.csproj", "Sido-Api-Data/"]
COPY ["Sido-Data-Access/Sido-Data-Access.csproj", "Sido-Data-Access/"]
COPY ["Sido-Models/Sido-Models.csproj", "Sido-Models/"]
COPY ["Sido-Business/Sido-Business.csproj", "Sido-Business/"]

# Restaurar dependencias y construir el proyecto
RUN dotnet restore "Sido-Api-Data/Sido-Api-Data.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Sido-Api-Data"
RUN dotnet build --no-restore "Sido-Api-Data.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION

# Crear usuario no root y ejecutar como dicho usuario
ARG USER=default
RUN apk add --no-cache sudo \
    && adduser -D $USER \
    && echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$USER \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USER \
    && apk del sudo
USER $USER

# Ejecutar la aplicación
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--no-build", "--no-launch-profile", "-c", "$BUILD_CONFIGURATION", "--"]

Imagen en el pipeline que da el error.

Link de la vulnerabilidad:
https://scout.docker.com/vulnerabilities/id/CVE-2024-38095?s=github&n=System.Formats.Asn1&t=nuget&vr=%3E%3D5.0.0-preview.7.20364.11%2C%3C6.0.1

Yo estoy mal o ahi dice que lo que es vulnerable es uno de los paquetes de tu solucion?

ahi dice que debes actualizar este paquete https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Formats.Asn1/6.0.1 no se como sea en .net pero si ese paquete es dependencia de otro paquete, el que debes actualizar es ese otro paquete, si por el contrario lo instalaste tu directamente no hay lio, solo actualizalo ...
